# What are the differences between "receptacle" and "container"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology, synonyms

Generally, both "receptacle" and "container" refer to an object that contains some other object(s). What are the differences between these two words? Do they differ in meaning, usage, or origin?

I searched "difference between receptacle and container" in Google but the only two relevant results ([[1]](http://wikidiff.com/container/receptacle), [[2]](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/125616-RECEPTACLE-VS-CONTAINER)) can both be summarized as "They are basically the same thing".

Comment: "difference between receptacle and container" is not what you should search for on Google. Search for the words individually. Look at the images. Look at dictionary definitions. And tell us that. :)

Comment: Thank you @NVZ for your comments. I have edited my question to include the research I have done. I do not consider Google Image results to be helpful since I have seen both words being used in a general sense (an object that can contain some other object(s) instead of referring to any specific type of receptacle/container.).

Comment: As usual with synonyms, there is an unpredictable range of situations where the two terms are interchangeable, and places where they're definitely not. The things they stack on purpose-built ships are always 'containers' and a coin slot is _never_ a 'container'. Even where they may be swapped, 'receptacle' is in a far higher register.

Comment: @NVZ I have indeed looked up both words' dictionary definition. Both words have some special usages (for example, "receptacle" can mean "an organ or structure that receives a secretion, eggs, sperm, etc."). But I am more interested in their differences when being used in a general sense.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't plug a lamp into a "container".

Comment: The point about *receptacle* being of a  much higher register is absolutely critical. It is also something you'll never  get out of a dictionary. It doesn't matter if it looks like some dictionary appears to suggest these word have similar meanings because in actual use they're nearly never interchangeable. People will look at you funny if you use *receptacle* much.

Answer (score 8):

Receptacle <-- receives something

Container <-- contains something

Sender <-- sends something

A receiver uses his receptacle to receive something. Then he puts it into his container (memory) to keep it contained and safe.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/receptacle

> 1375-1425; Middle English (< Old French) < Latin receptāculum reservoir, equivalent to receptā(re) to take again, **receive back** (frequentative of recipere to receive ) + -culum -cle2

Comment: “Receptacle <-- receives something”

--- I was thinking the same thing, but New Oxford American Dictionary’s first definition for receptacle is “an object or space used to contain something”.

Comment: That which receives also contains, so there is some overlap. It is all about the usage. A glass jar is a container; put a funnel with a filter in it and use the contraption to make some cream cheese, however, and the jar becomes a receptacle for the whey.

Comment: While there's a lot of overlap, to my mind, a receptacle is (often) designed to receive _something specific_ whereas a container is (often) more general purpose in the things it can contain.

Answer (score 6):

An instructive synonym for *receptacle* in an electrical sense is *socket* (discussed in depth here under [difference between “socket” and “outlet”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/42259/48571)).  *Socket* can't usually be a synonym for *container*.

A major part of the difference in use is to do with the purpose. You can call a litter bin a *trash container* or a *trash receptacle*. In the former case you're emphasising storage, in the latter, you're emphasising acceptance.

You may have been a little unlucky with your choice of dictionary.  Merriam-Webster has "one that *receives* and contains something", Cambridge has "a container used for storing or *putting* objects in" (emphasis mine in both cases).

Answer (score 1):

A trash bin may be called a trash receptacle or a trash container, but a power receptacle would not be called a power container. The "receiving" done by a power receptacle, in my connotation is that it receives the plug from the device to be powered.

There is some overlap but, as others have mentioned, the root of "receptacle" is "receive" and the root of "container" is "contain".

[Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=power%20receptacle&oq=power%20receptacle&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5126j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I just realized that Chris H. posted an answer very similar to mine about 3 hours earlier. I'll leave mine here in-case someone finds a little more enlightenment from it.

Answer (score 1):

You could look to the common phrase, "place the item in the proper receptacle", and derive that receptacle is a more specified type of container; a container designated to receive a particular item. Consider where trash is sorted by different materials; glass goes into the glass receptacle, paper in the paper receptacle, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in what the object is used for.  When I see "container" I think of something people put stuff into that the want to store for some indefinite period of time, then remove and use.  When I see "receptacle" I think of something that people put stuff into for a specific reason, that someone else is going to remove to use for whatever purpose.

Examples:

I put my leftover dinner in a plastic container so I can take it to work tomorrow.

I dropped the empty can in the aluminum receptacle.

"Receptacle" can also refer to where you plug electrical cords, but, in AE at least, it is more often called an "outlet".